# Refresh ping timer

Tags: python

I'm writing a script which will alert me if my net drops or one of my servers drops. Below is the code:

```
import subprocess
import time
iplist=["127.0.0.1","8.8.8.8"]
#iplist=["127.0.0.1","8.8.8.8", "983.42.23.342"]

def Pingisdown(ip, p):
    timeouts = time.time()
    p.wait()
    while p.poll(): 
        timeout = time.time()
        print(ip)
        print(timeout - timeouts)
        #length
        if p.poll() == 0:
            break   
            print("YAYYY")

for ip in iplist:
    p = subprocess.Popen('ping '+ip,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    p.wait()
    if p.poll(): 
        Pingisdown(ip, p)
    else:
        print (ip+" is up")
```

The issue is when I enable my network once it's back up it still counts as offline.
The p.poll reports back 1 if offline or 0 if online if im correct, either way in the while loop it keeps recording as 1 once i switch it back on.

EDIT:

I have reworked it using a good section of the provided code. Instead of using a while it uses if conditions, this is due to the ping all ready repeating. This is now working

```
import subprocess
import time
iplist=["127.0.0.1","8.8.8.8"]
#iplist=["127.0.0.1","8.8.8.8", "983.42.23.342"]

def Pingisdown2(ip, p, timeouts):
    p = subprocess.Popen('ping '+ip,stdout=subprocess.PIPE) 
    p.wait()
    if p.poll(): 
        Pingisdown(ip, p, timeouts) 
    else:
        print (ip+" is up") 
        timeout = time.time()
        print(timeout - timeouts)

def Pingisdown(ip, p, timeouts):
    print(ip)
    Pingisdown2(ip, p, timeouts)

for ip in iplist:
    p = subprocess.Popen('ping '+ip,stdout=subprocess.PIPE) 
    p.wait()
    if p.poll(): 
        timeouts = time.time()
        Pingisdown(ip, p, timeouts) 
        timeout = time.time()
    else:
        print (ip+" is up")
```

Comment: Does the ip of sevice is static ?

Comment: Im testing it using my local ip, il switch off my wifi then turn it back on. If i test with it on it works fine and returns ip is up, else it applys the function

Answer (score 1):

You're not running `ping` again each time you call `wait()` or `poll()` - you're just getting the result from the first run. As such, if it failed, the result is going to remain as a failure every time you call `poll()`.

Comment: I added the subprocess within the while loop. Would you show me how you would solve this please.

Comment: please show the code that you have tried. You can edit your question to add it

Answer (score 0):

Since you are interested in the status code of the ping command call the using of the [subprocess.check_call](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_call)  would be more appropriate. Also, pass args as the list instead of string, that's preferred way of calling bash command from python, please see the body of the while loop below:

```
try:
    # I've added -i and -c flags for fast ping command. Run `man ping` in terminal for flags description.
    subprocess.check_call(['ping', '-c', '5', '-i', ' 0.2', ip]) 
except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
    Pingisdown(ip) # NOTE: Update to process only ip.
else:
    print (ip+ " is up")
```

Please let me know if the error won't disappear after applying suggested handling.

Comment: Error remains of "4.423957824707031
8.8.8.8
4.423957824707031
8.8.8.8" even after turning on wi-fi again

Comment: @Phpuser what is `4.423957824707031` ? Try ping command by hand at the same time in terminal, what is the out of manual run ?

Comment: That's the timer I have running

Comment: @Phpuser What is the out of the manual ping command run in terminal ( at the same time as you expect to have check_call return 0)?

Comment: I don't understand what you are after i'm afraid. I just want to check if it's alive or not

Comment: @Phpuser I've updated my check_call function. Please try again. Trying to run locally, everything works. Did you added all code snippet I've provided or just part of it ?